# how to fetch <li> values in jquery and get the value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to get the value of this and get it on php:

```
$cart = $('#selected-seats')
```

here is the code:

```
 var price = <?php $price  = 400; echo $price;?>; //price
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var $cart = $('#selected-seats'), //Sitting Area
 $counter = $('#counter'), //Votes
 $total = $('#total'); //Total money    

 var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
    map: [  //Seating chart
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aa_aa',
        'aaaaa',        

    ],
    naming : {
        top : false,
        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
            return column;
        }
    },
    legend : { //Definition legend
        node : $('#legend'),
        items : [
            [ 'a', 'available',   'Option' ],
            [ 'a', 'unavailable', 'Sold']
        ]                   
    },

    click: function () { //Click event
        if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
        $('<li>'+(this.settings.row+1)+'_'+this.settings.label+'</li>')
                .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                .appendTo($cart);


            $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
            $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+price);


            return 'selected';
        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked
                //Update Number
                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                //update totalnum
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-price);

                //Delete reservation
                $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                //optional
                return 'available';
        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
            return 'unavailable';
        } else {
            return this.style();
        }
    }
});     

//sold seat
sc.get([]).status('unavailable');

});
//sum total money
function recalculateTotal(sc) {
var total = 0;
sc.find('selected').each(function () {
    total += price;
});

return total;
}
</script>
```

here is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7">
<br>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="seat-map">             
    </div>
    <div class="booking-details">
        <p>Time: <span>November 3, 21:00</span></p>
        <p>Seat: </p>
        <ul id="selected-seats"></ul>
        <p>No of Seats: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
        <p>Total: <b>P<span id="total">0</span></b></p>
            <br>    
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" name="book" onclick="book();">Book</button>

        <div id="legend"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

</div>   
</div>
</div>
```

how can i get the value of the $cart and get that value in php?

im new at using jquery and has no background at using ajax, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getLiData = [];

$("ul li").each(function(){
    getLiData.push($(this).html());
});
```

Then just Send it to a callback php file with an `Ajax` request

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an endpoint on **Server side (PHP)** that accepting JSON string and then send data via [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from **Client side (Javascript)**

**For Exmaple:**

**Server Side (PHP)**

```
<?php
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($payload);

//TODO: Your handling logic here
// Accessing the array by $request->{'selectedSeats'}

$rsp = array('success'=>true);
echo json_encode($rsp);
?>
```

**Client Side (Javascript)**

```
var request = {
    selectedSeats: []
};

$("#selected-seats li").each(function(){
    request.selectedSeats.push($(this).html());
});

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api.php",
    data: request,
    success: function(rsp){
        if(rsp.success){
            alert("Success");
        }else{
            alert("Fail");
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first let me answer your immediate questions..

This will give you an array of the selected seat ids:

```
var seatsInCart = $cart.children().map(function(i, el) { return $(el).data('seatId') })
```

You can then post your data via Ajax like this:

```
$.post("cart.php", { seats: seatsInCart })
  .done(
    function(data) {
      alert("Response from server: " + data);
    }
  );
```

However, why don't you simply store the seat ids - or whatever you will use to identify the selected seats - at the moment it is selected in a javascript variable? It is unnecessarily complex to extract this from the DOM.

Even better would be to then have the list of seats be rendered depending on that array. Otherwise you may soon find yourself in a muddle of jQuery DOM manipulations which are very fragile and break everytime you touch anything.

Have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/ which is a great tool for such use cases and easily understood. If you feel especially daring you might even consider to use ReactJS here.